# How to make nav divs responsive and not overlap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my navigation responsive. It looks the way I want it to look on a full screen/desktop but when I view it on a tablet or smart phone the items overlap and look awful. I've played with clearing, spacing, but my CSS knowledge has run dry.

Here's the snippet of my current navigation

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#navWrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #444445;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav2 {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="navWrapper">
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/products/">products</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/about-us/">about us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="{{ 'LOGO.png' | asset_url }}" border="0" style="max-width: 100%; height:auto;" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/community/contact/">contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav2"><a href="/pages/products/">buy now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of giving nav class to every div. You have to try bootstraps nav class.It will automatically hide your navigation bar. menu will show only on clicking the button.  Define your menu inside a `<ul>`
check the link below:
http://www.bootply.com/lbIb5ZaHbq#

Check menu for small device

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```css
#navWrapper {white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 99%;}
.nav {width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 3%;
    white-space: normal;}

.logo {height: auto; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="nav">
    <div id="navWrapper">
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/products/">products</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/about-us/">about us</a></div>
    <div class="nav logo"><a href="/"><img src="{{ 'LOGO.png' | asset_url }}" border="0" style="max-width: 100%; height:auto;"/></a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/community/contact/">contact</a></div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/products/">buy now</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is solid on desktop - but is right-aligned horizontally off of the screen on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

For responsive look you should always go with media queries. 
I changed your CSS just to show you how it works. I did not apply any changes on your logo because you did not provided logo size.

Basically you make query for every resolution you want and change size of elements according to that resolution.

In your case here i just changed percent of font-size on some resolution and removed *#navWrapper width* (i presume you wanted to make it responsive over that value). I hope you get the point how you should make things responsive.

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#navWrapper {
 
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #444445;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav2 {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#navWrapper {
  
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 130%;
  color: #444445;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav2 {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 130%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#navWrapper {
  
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #444445;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav2 {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
}
@media (max-width: 546px) {
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#navWrapper {
  
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #444445;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav2 {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
}
@media (max-width: 360px) {
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#navWrapper {
  
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #444445;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav2 {
  width: 18%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.logo {
  float: left;
  width: 26%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <div id="navWrapper">
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/products/">products</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/pages/about-us/">about us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <img src="{{ 'LOGO.png' | asset_url }}" border="0" style="max-width: 100%; height:auto;" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav"><a href="/community/contact/">contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav2"><a href="/pages/products/">buy now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```